I have two last names and want both Arxiv and google scholar to show them both everytime. How can I do this?
So I have two last names: FirstLastname SecondLastname, Nicolás. But both ArXiv and Google Scholar abbreviate this as SecondLastname, Nicolás F.
I have colleagues who have literally given in to the pressure and changed the last name they go by just because of this, but I don't want to do that. How can I ask the platforms to display my name properly?

Since this is common in many places (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name), it is a shame that these sites don't have a standardized way to choose the form of the surname.

This is a really common problem for people whose names do not follow the British / American convention of "First name [middle name] last name". There is a lot of variation even within Europe, let alone around the world, yet system developers are often unaware. Unfortunately everybody I know with this problem (some Spanish, some Indian , some from various parts of Africa) have just decided on what their two-name professional name will be and adopted that. With Google Scholar in particular, which has approximately no support, it'd be tough to fight it.

Voting to leave open as this is a common problem with academic systems facing many academics.

Actually, my spouse, American, born to American's has two first names. Correct on birth certificate, passport, ... but a lot of systems can't handle it.

@Buffy two first names as opposed to first and middle names? Isn't a second first name your middle name by definition in the US? It is for me, anyway.

@terdon, nope, two separate words for the first name, plus a middle name. As per the birth certificate, which was created in the pre computerized era. Not a problem then. Something like Bonny Sue (first name), Marie, (middle name), Ogalvie. And Bonnysue or BonnieSue or Bonnie-Sue just don't work and are never used or implied. Note that names are actually fairly arbitrary, though many are traditional. Her mother was just a bit creative and not able to predict what would happen in the computer era. Our COVID boosters were delayed for several minutes while the drugstore puzzled it out.

Naming of some people among the first inhabitants of what is now North America (First Nations) can have many "parts": Henry Cold Moon Rising, for a made-up example.

Because nobody has linked this yet... https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

This question is similar to: How do you handle a double barrel name in citations/publishing?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Just put both surnames in the single surname field, as if it were a compound surname. No need for a hyphen. Just treat your two surnames as a single compound block when dealing with systems that suppose a single surname. For Spanish names at least this works just fine.

Early on in my career my PhD advisor suggested I hyphenate my name -- and I did. While there is still some confusion at times, it has minimized the problems, and I am usually alphabetized by L instead of by R, and my lastname is typically recognized as Lozano-Robledo. Both Google scholar and arXiv recognize me as Lozano-Robledo.

Better, though, if you can maintain the traditions of your ethnic/cultural/ancestral background rather than to have to submit to the incompetence of computers. And, not so great if you consider Robledo to be primary, which might be the case in some cultures.

The hyphen is usually unnecessary if you just stick both apellidos in the same field separated by a space (this is almost always accepted, while hyphens often are not).

One option - which is probably not ideal - might be to put a hyphen instead of a space between your two last names. Since hyphenated names are common in white America, web systems are more likely to handle them.

Now I'm wondering if a non-breaking space (or a similar character) would trick at least some of the automated systems.

@JiK: problem is with services that aren't expecting that. I don't think Nicolas FirstLastName&nbsp;SecondLastName (or a ton of other possible rendering errors) looks very nice :)

Or if the non-breaking space is simply dropped. Note that things were fine before computers. This is a relatively easy problem for computers to handle, being only a few options. Why it hasn't been done is lack of attention by those specifying the systems. Computers are good at this stuff. Maybe ridicule of those systems and their creators is the solution.

I'm a developer and although this is an easy problem to solve, the fact it exists also makes sense to me.  It's common to sanitize inputs, and I can easily see either a developer or business analyst saying "let's only allow these characters" - omitting spaces due to not thinking of this "common" use-case.

@aaaaaa, I might describe that "business analyst" as a chauvinistic fool. If they have a world-wide audience, they need a world-wide solution. Why should a computer system be chauvinistic?

I think you're being unnecessarily judgemental.  Not everyone thinks of last names as having spaces.  Not everyone travels or meets people from other cultures, regardless whether they're employed to build a product for them.  I think the fact multiple programs missed this case is proof that this isn't just one or two poeple who should be ridiculed

@aaaaaa IMHO if somebody is employed to build a product for worldwide use, then it's their job to learn about worldwide requirements.

Yup flyto, and the world should be perfect too.  Let's judge everyone who isn't.
